# Delete an object from nested array in openjson SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, json-query

I want to delete the `"AttributeName" : "Manufacturer"` from the below json in SQL Server 2016:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[{"Type":"G","GroupBy":[],
"Attributes":[{"AttributeName":"Class Designation / Compressive Strength"},{"AttributeName":"Size"},{"AttributeName":"Manufacturer"}]}]'
```

This is the query I tried which is not working

```
select JSON_MODIFY((
select JSON_Query(@json, '$[0].Attributes') as res),'$.AttributeName.Manufacturer', null)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working solution using the [for json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-nested-json-output-with-path-mode-sql-server) and [open json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql). The point is to:

1. Identify the item you wish to delete and replace it with `NULL`. This is done by `JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$[0].Attributes[2]', null)`. We're simply saying, take the 2nd element in `Attributes` and replace it by null
2. Convert this array to a row set. We need to somehow get rid of this `null` element and that's something we can filter easily in SQL by `where [value] is not null`
3. Assemble it all back to original JSON. That's done by `FOR JSON AUTO`

*Please bear in mind one important aspect of such JSON data transformations:*

JSON is designed for information exchange or eventually to store the information. But you should avoid more complicated data manipulation on SQL level.

Anyway, solution here:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[{"Type": "G","GroupBy": [],"Attributes": [{"AttributeName": "Class Designation / Compressive Strength"}, {"AttributeName": "Size"}, {"AttributeName": "Manufacturer"}]}]';            

with src as
(
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(
        JSON_Query(
            JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$[0].Attributes[2]', null) , '$[0].Attributes'))
)
select JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$[0].Attributes', (
    select JSON_VALUE([value], '$.AttributeName') as [AttributeName] from src
    where [value] is not null
    FOR JSON AUTO 
))
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. works as expected. One small clarification , In real scenario I know only the **AttributeName = Manufacturer** to be deleted but not its Index  as 2  "JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$[0].Attributes[**2**]', null)".

Comment: @Jebin You see :) Yet another reason to move the transformation logic somewhere else. It will get increasingly more and more painful. Anyway, the only way out here is to replace the `[2]` index by subselect.. a query that will find the element index by its attributename value.