# Conditionally delete a json object from Json Array in SQL Server 2017

Tags: json, sql-server-2017, open-json

I am using Json Array to store child table records as a column in parent table. Now I have a requirement to conditionally delete one of the record from json array. If it would have been a table, I could have used delete command with the condition but how can I delete a record form Json array stored as varchar(max) column in SQL Server. I have gone through below url and can see command to query and modify the data but what about delete?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: provide sample JSON and expected result

Comment: see this answer for solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47095742/3266499